# how to remove hyperlink on menu's icon but it should open submenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

My Question Is When I click Menu's icon (like plus or dropdown) and if its have any           link it shouldn't move to page but it show submenu first then only
I have applied this JS :

```
let plus = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item > a");
console.log(plus);
for (var i = 0; i < plus.length; i++){
  console.log(plus[i]);
  plus[i].addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    let plusParent = e.target.parentElement;
    console.log(plusParent);    
    plusParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
  });
}
```

[in this image you can check where I want to open submenu on click icon's but not redirect to parent icon's link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LirfH.png)

Comment: Is [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp), what you were thinking of?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't working on my code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to prevent the event of  tag first so it wouldn't jump to the link. you can use e.preventDefault() for doing the same.

```
let plus = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item > a");
console.log(plus);
for (var i = 0; i < plus.length; i++){
  console.log(plus[i]);
  plus[i].addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-plus')) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent link to open new page because plus icon is clicked
    }

    let plusParent = e.target.parentElement;
    console.log(plusParent);    
    plusParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Farz,
Thanks for answer, it is working fine. Just another doubt, now if I am clicking on that link it does not seem to work at all: 
Group (menu-item) (it has link which we have prevented according to your code)
  activity 
  member

Comment: do you have a link and a plus icon separately ? and you want that the link click with open link but click on plus will just open sub menu or what ? i think i am not able to understand your question properly. can you please elaborate it more or just post some reference photo.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/24x64ax   (this is link of what I am trying to do)

And this is the code :

<li id="menu-item-127" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-127 menu-item--has-toggle showMenu"><a href="http://buddyx.local/groups/">Groups</a><button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Expand child menu"><i class="fas fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" onclick="myFunction()"></i>
   </button>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 sub menu code
</ul>
</li>

as you can see the Li (Group have link)

Comment: Got you, the solution is you need to conditionally use e.preventDefault() that is if the clicked element (e.target) is having class fa-plus then prevent event otherwise don't prevent it. something like if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-plus') { e.preventDefault() }

Comment: i updated my answer with working solution of you problem. please have a look and let me if you more help with it.

Comment: Hi Farz 
Thanks again but when I am implementing current code it still redirecting to group page.
You can check following URL
https://wpex.in/apoorva/

Comment: hey @ApoorvaSingh, i cannot see any plus icon beside Groups from my side. see this screenshot -> https://nimb.ws/QawG15